# Why does python allow omitting space in front of boolean operator but not after?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, boolean-operations

This works:
`1and 1` and evaluates to `1`.

This `1 and1` throws a SyntaxError.

Why is the space in front optional, but the space after not?

Comment: Due to the ambiguity, I'd guess - an identifier can't start with a number, but it can end with one/`1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#whitespace-between-tokens):

> Whitespace is needed between two tokens only if their concatenation could otherwise be interpreted as a different token...

`and1` is a valid [*identifier*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), so `and1` can be interpreted as a single token, whereas `1and` isn't, so it can't be.

Presumably at least partly because of this, PEP-8 [recommends](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) always surrounding them with spaces:

> Always surround these binary operators with a single space on either side: assignment (`=`), augmented assignment (`+=`, `-=` etc.), comparisons (`==`, `<`, `>`, `!=`, `<>`, `<=`, `>=`, `in`, `not in`, `is`, `is not`), Booleans (`and`, `or`, `not`).